# Program immediately closes in SDL

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl

I am trying to build my first program in SDL 1.2 simply to get familiar with SDL.
I have a headache trying to understand why my program immediately closes.

Does this have to do with the way I'm compiling it?

Here is all of my code and don't worry about trying to find logical errors that don't have to do with the error at hand. I simply want to find out why the program is immediately closing upon starting it.

Guy.h:

```
#ifndef GUY_H
#define GUY_H

class Guy{
    public:
        Guy(int, int);
        void move();
        void adjustVelocity(int, int);
        int getX();
        int getY();
        int getXVel();
        int getYVel();
    private:
        int xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel;
};
#endif
```

Guy.cpp:

```
#include "Guy.h"

Guy::Guy(int x, int y){
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
}
void Guy::move(){
    xPos += xVel;
    yPos += yVel;
}
void Guy::adjustVelocity(int x, int y){
    xVel += x;
    yVel += y;
}
int Guy::getX(){
    return xPos;
}
int Guy::getY(){
        return yPos;
}
int Guy::getXVel(){
    return xVel;
}
int Guy::getYVel(){
    return yVel;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "Guy.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool init();
bool loadAllFiles();
void paintScreen();
void update();
bool handle();
void cleanUp();

void addSurface(int, int, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Rect* clip = NULL);
SDL_Surface* loadFile(std::string);
SDL_Surface* Screen;
SDL_Surface* BackgroundIMG;
SDL_Surface* GuyIMG;
Guy* Hunter;


int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    std::cout << "Why won't it even cout this?? :(" << endl;
    if(!init()){
        return 1;
    }
    if(!loadAllFiles()){
        return 2;
    }
    Hunter = new Guy(0,0);
    paintScreen();
    while(handle()){
        update();
    }

    cleanUp();
    return 0;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    Screen = SDL_SetDisplayMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    SDL_Flip(Screen);
    SDL_Delay(1000);
}

bool init(){
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)==-1){
        return false;
    }
    Screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
    if(Screen==NULL){
        return false;
    }
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("First SDL Test On Own", NULL);
    return true;
}

bool loadAllFiles(){
    BackgroundIMG = loadFile("Background.png");
    GuyIMG = loadFile("Guy.png");
    if(BackgroundIMG==NULL || GuyIMG==NULL){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

void paintScreen(){
    addSurface(0, 0, BackgroundIMG, Screen);
    addSurface(Hunter->getX(), Hunter->getY(), GuyIMG, Screen);
    SDL_Flip(Screen);
}

void update(){
    Hunter->move();
    addSurface(Hunter->getX(), Hunter->getY(), GuyIMG, Screen);
    SDL_Flip(Screen);
}

bool handle(){ 
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
        if(event.type==SDL_QUIT){
            return false;
        }
        else if(event.type==SDL_KEYDOWN){
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym){
                case SDLK_UP:
                    Hunter->adjustVelocity(0, -1);
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    Hunter->adjustVelocity(0, 1);
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    Hunter->adjustVelocity(1, 0);
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    Hunter->adjustVelocity(-1, 0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void cleanUp(){
    SDL_FreeSurface(GuyIMG);
    SDL_FreeSurface(BackgroundIMG);
    SDL_Quit();
    delete Hunter;
}



void addSurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination, SDL_Rect* clip){
    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;
    SDL_BlitSurface(source, clip, destination, &offset);
}

SDL_Surface* loadFile(std::string s){
    SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load(s.c_str());
    if(surface==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        SDL_Surface* opsurface = SDL_DisplayFormat(surface);
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        return opsurface;
    }
}
```

My makefile:

```
all: main.o
        g++ -o run main.o Guy.o -lSDL -lSDL_image
main.o: Guy.o
        g++ -c main.cpp
Guy.o:
        g++ -c Guy.cpp
```

Whenever I compile it with this makefile, I get no errors.

Comment: Is this a console application in a windowing system?  Many times console applications will end and the windowing system will close the window immediately.

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling it in terminal, but I have an XFCE desktop.
I was experimenting with this and I think that the problem is that the makefile for some reason was not updating the .o files. It therefore was running an old version of the program. That would explain why a cout would not work.

Comment: Update:

When experimenting, I found out that if I don't check if Screen==NULL, in bool init(), the screen will not immediately disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program immediately closes because you are using `SDL_PollEvent(&event)`. This function will return false if there is no event to process, which in your case is happening when the program starts. If a user has to provide window inputs, ***the fact that there is no event to process is the rule and not the exception.***

You have 2 alternatives :

1. Switch to [SDL_WaitEvent](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WaitEvent). It is really similar to SDL_PollEvent, but the difference is that it is a blocking call.It has the advantage of being simple to obtain the behavior you expect from your app.
2. Stay with `SDL_PollEvent`, and add a mechanism to defer execution when there is no event to process. In general people use a [SDL_Delay](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Delay) with a delay of 0 or 10. The advantage is that you have control of what the app does when there is no events.

Example of process loop scenario.

```
SDL_Event event;
bool stop = false;
while(!stop){
    bool got_event = SDL_PollEvent(&event) > 0;
    if(got_event){
       stop = processEvent(event);
    }
    else {
        if(backGroundWorkTodo()){
           doBackGroundWork();
        }
        else{
          //may defer execution
          SDL_Delay(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I do have one more question...
Is it possible to take in a constant input in SDL?
Like if I held down the arrow key, would it continue to react?
Right now, if I hold down the arrow key, SDL only recognizes that it was typed once; not that I'm holding it down.

Comment: yes you can recognize this with an internal state for the key. When the event is SDL_KEYDOWN , it means the key is being held down until you receive SDL_KEYUP.